# Angular2 local components / template reuse

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm writing some Angular2 templates that have repetitive portions with different containers. In this case, the view can change if things are grouped and if multi section mode is enabled. Please excuse the long example, but something like this:

```
<template [ngIf]="isCategoryGrouped">
    <div *ngFor="#categories of categories">
        <div>{{ categories.category.name }}</div>
        <div *ngFor="#thing of categories.things">
            <label *ngIf="isMultiSelectMode">
                <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateThingSelection(thing, $event)" />
                <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
            </label>
            <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="selectThing(thing)" *ngIf="! isMultiSelectMode">
                <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<template [ngIf]="! isCategoryGrouped">
    <div *ngFor="#thing of things">
        <label *ngIf="isMultiSelectMode">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateThingSelection(thing, $event)" />
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </label>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="selectThing(thing)" *ngIf="! isMultiSelectMode">
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'd really like to reuse portions of this without having to write a completely separate component and wire it all together, which would require a TypeScript file and a template. One method would be with local components, something like this:

```
<sub-component selector="thing-list" things="input">
    <div *ngFor="#thing of things">
        <label *ngIf="isMultiSelectMode">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateThingSelection(thing, $event)"/>
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </label>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="selectThing(thing)" *ngIf="! isMultiSelectMode">
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
</sub-component>

<template [ngIf]="isCategoryGrouped">
    <div *ngFor="#categories of categories">
        <div>{{ categories.category.name }}</div>
        <thing-list things="categories.things" />
    </div>
</template>
<thing-list [ngIf]="! isCategoryGrouped" things="things" />
```

I realize the above is a rough sketch and probably wouldn't work as is, but the apparent inability to reuse portions of the view like this is unfortunate. This sort of thing is quite simple in React, if I understand correctly.

I'm curious about elegant ways others have solved the reuse-of-portions-of-view without going so far as to write a new component (which our designers would then need to know about and style, etc...). Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me which portions of the view you want to reuse in which way.

Answer (score 4):

If your sections are identical in structure, just different in data, you could come up with a more generic model. Instead of referring to `category` and `thing` directly, map them into a generic object that you populate in a service before it gets to the view.

```
<div *ngFor="#item of items">
        ---
</div>
```

Here items would either be populated from things or categories.

You can then call it like so

```
<component [items]="fromThings"></component>
<component [items]="fromCategories"></component>
```

You are basically normalizing the view by not depending on the actual objects directly.

Comment: The issue at hand is when the children need to be duplicated with different parents, so I can't use a loop. The second part of this answer is exactly what I want to avoid -- making a new component. The reason I don't want to make a new component is that the duplicated portions of the tree are very specific to this view. I basically want something analogues to inner or method classes in the java/scala universe.

Comment: So with this suggestion you keep it as one component, but pass it an object populated from the two different variations. You normalize it basically to a third model object.

Comment: Right... but you still have a separate component from the context where it's used, which is specifically what I'm trying to avoid. See the answer by Günter, which points to a pull request for the feature that I'm asking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `*ngFor` with `[ngForTemplate]` or the upcoming [NgInsert](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8021) (name will be changed) to make parts of your template reusable.

Comment: `ngInsert` seems new term to me, what the use of same, good if you update your answer with bit more explanation.

Comment: See the link. It will be named differently. It just allows you to stamp referenced templates. I hope to get more information about the requirements first and then I'll refine my answer.

Comment: This looks awesome, and is almost exactly what I want. Can't wait for it to drop into a beta. Any rough estimate of when that will happen?

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps I'll write my own version of that component for use in the meantime. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use `<ng-template>`

```
<ng-template #headerPanel>
    <header>
       This is my reusable header.
    </header>
</ng-template>
```

Then use like this:

```
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerPanel"></ng-container>
```

[Official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

Note: I'm not knowledgeable enough to explain difference between `[ngTemplateOutlet]` and `*ngTemplateOutlet` but if someone else wants to edit this answer or add another feel free.

Answer (score 0):

Call component recursively in template.

`isList` control which part to be used, default `false`.

**thing.html**

```html
<template [ngIf]="isLlist">
    <div *ngFor="#thing of things">
        <label *ngIf="isMultiSelectMode">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateThingSelection(thing, $event)"/>
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </label>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="selectThing(thing)" *ngIf="! isMultiSelectMode">
            <img [src]="thing.image" /> {{ thing.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<template [ngIf]="!isList">

    <template [ngIf]="isCategoryGrouped">
        <div *ngFor="#categories of categories">
            <div>{{ categories.category.name }}</div>
            <my-thing-component [isList]="true" [things]="categories.things"></my-thing-component>
        </div>
    </template>

    <templete [ngIf]="! isCategoryGrouped">
        <my-thing-component [isList]="true" [things]="things"></my-thing-component>
    </templete>

</template>
```

**thing.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-thing-component',
    templateUrl: 'thing.html' 
})
export class ThingComponent {
    @Input() isList = false;
    @Input() things;

    //Fill in the rest
}
```