# ionic 2 template reuse

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to have a "template" that I can reuse on multiple pages, basically each of the pages that will utilize this html template will pass the object with the data and the template will render based on the passed in object.

**Scenario**

I have 4 tabs, tab 1 and tab 2 pages have a section called "events" and the data will be different for each of the event templates but it will have the same html same structure, the only difference will be is me passing the events object that has different data.

Just need to know where do I  put my "events" template html and how do I add it to these 2 pages and pass the data object on render.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this. I think it may be creating a component that has your template and calling it with some parameters. I'm using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612205/angular2-local-components-template-reuse as a hint.

Answer (score -1):

Components can share a template, just enter the path in the component decorator.

e.g.

```
//page 1
@Component({
   templateUrl: "path/to/template"
})
//page 2
@Component({
   templateUrl: "path/to/template"
})
```

In the scenario you are describing however it sounds like you just need some components.

I would generate a component called `events` and a component called `event`

`$ ionic g component events`

`$ ionic g component event`

In each tab (that has an events section) add your `<events [yourEventsArray]></events>` component. And in the events component add the `<event *ngfor="let event of events" [event]="event"></event>` component